# Writing a function that reads both column y and text "y" in str_remove

Tags: r, string, function, dplyr, stringr

I'm writing a function in R for some code cleaning that involves removing some text in a string. I've got the following dataframe:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <-c("y_a","y_b","y_c","y_d","y_e")
z <-c("z_f","z_g","z_h","z_i","z_j")
df <- (x, y, z)
```

And I'm trying to clear the y_ and z_ out of columns y and z respectively.

Normally I'd write it as

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(y=str_remove(y,"y_"))
```

But I want to write a function so I can repeat. Right now my function looks like:

```
remove_weird_letter <- function(LETTER) {
mutate(LETTER=str_remove(LETTER,"LETTER_"))
}

df <- remove_weird_letter(y)
df <- remove_weird_letter(z)
```

But it's not reading seeing "LETTER" as a reference to the object in the function, so it's not removing what it needs to. How do I modify my syntax so that it knows to both reference a column called LETTER and text containing LETTER?

Thank you!

Comment: This dplyr documentation has some good info about why your function doesn't work: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html - The accepted answer is a better way to do it though, no need for mutate. But in the docs "glue" and "embracing" syntax can help in certain cases, e.g., 
```
remove_weird_letter <- function(data, LETTER) {
    mutate(data, "{LETTER}" := str_remove(data[[LETTER]], paste0("^", LETTER, "_")))
}
df %>% remove_weird_letter(., "y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.
The function accepts a column and removes everything up to including the first underscore from the beginning of the strings.
Three examples are given.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

remove_weird_letter <- function(x) {
  pattern <- "^[^_]+_"
  stringr::str_remove(x, pattern)
}

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <-c("y_a","y_b","y_c","y_d","y_e")
z <-c("z_f","z_g","z_h","z_i","z_j")
x827402 <- paste0("x827402_", 1:5)
x19538 <- paste0("x19538_", 1:5)
x300004192 <- paste0("x300004192_", 1:5)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, x827402, x19538, x300004192)

# remove column name from one column
df %>%
  mutate(y = remove_weird_letter(y))
#>   x y   z   x827402   x19538   x300004192
#> 1 1 a z_f x827402_1 x19538_1 x300004192_1
#> 2 2 b z_g x827402_2 x19538_2 x300004192_2
#> 3 3 c z_h x827402_3 x19538_3 x300004192_3
#> 4 4 d z_i x827402_4 x19538_4 x300004192_4
#> 5 5 e z_j x827402_5 x19538_5 x300004192_5

# remove column names from several columns
df %>%
  mutate(across(y:x300004192, ~ remove_weird_letter(.x)))
#>   x y z x827402 x19538 x300004192
#> 1 1 a f       1      1          1
#> 2 2 b g       2      2          2
#> 3 3 c h       3      3          3
#> 4 4 d i       4      4          4
#> 5 5 e j       5      5          5

# remove column names from several columns
df %>%
  mutate(across(y:x300004192, ~ remove_weird_letter(.x)))
#>   x y z x827402 x19538 x300004192
#> 1 1 a f       1      1          1
#> 2 2 b g       2      2          2
#> 3 3 c h       3      3          3
#> 4 4 d i       4      4          4
#> 5 5 e j       5      5          5

# remove column names from columns starting with "x"
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~ remove_weird_letter(.x)))
#>   x   y   z x827402 x19538 x300004192
#> 1 1 y_a z_f       1      1          1
#> 2 2 y_b z_g       2      2          2
#> 3 3 y_c z_h       3      3          3
#> 4 4 y_d z_i       4      4          4
#> 5 5 y_e z_j       5      5          5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way that you could do it if the number of characters at the beginning of the string is not fixed? The undesired characters will always be at the beginning, but in the actual dataset I'm working with, "y" could be "x827402" or "x19538" or "x300004192" (but it will always match the column name!).

Comment: @Catherine It is important information that the string to be removed always matches the column name. Can you edit the question with your comment text, so that it makes the question clearer, please?

Comment: @Catherine Done, see the edit.